# Unable to insert background image in Boilerplate template

Tags: css, image, background, boilerplate

I just started messing around with the Boilerplate template. And i'm having trouble getting my background image to appear.

css:

```
body {
font-size: 1em;
line-height: 1.4;
background-image: url (img/bg2.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;

}
```

Some insight would be appreciated i'm pretty much an amateur

Thanks :)

EDIT:

Full css here:

```
/*
 * HTML5 Boilerplate
 *
 * What follows is the result of much research on cross-browser styling.
 * Credit left inline and big thanks to Nicolas Gallagher, Jonathan Neal,
 * Kroc Camen, and the H5BP dev community and team.
 */

/* ==========================================================================
   Base styles: opinionated defaults
   ========================================================================== */

html,
button,
input,
select,
textarea {
    color: #222;
}

body {
font-size: 1em;
line-height: 1.4;
background-image:url("bg2.png");
}

html body {
background-image:url("bg2.png")!important;
}


/*
 * Remove text-shadow in selection highlight: h5bp.com/i
 * These selection rule sets have to be separate.
 * Customize the background color to match your design.
 */

::-moz-selection {
    background: #b3d4fc;
    text-shadow: none;
}

::selection {
    background: #b3d4fc;
    text-shadow: none;
}

/*
 * A better looking default horizontal rule
 */

hr {
    display: block;
    height: 1px;
    border: 0;
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
    margin: 1em 0;
    padding: 0;
}

/*
 * Remove the gap between images and the bottom of their containers: h5bp.com/i/440
 */

img {
    vertical-align: middle;
}

/*
 * Remove default fieldset styles.
 */

fieldset {
    border: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

/*
 * Allow only vertical resizing of textareas.
 */

textarea {
    resize: vertical;
}

/* ==========================================================================
   Chrome Frame prompt
   ========================================================================== */

.chromeframe {
    margin: 0.2em 0;
    background: #ccc;
    color: #000;
    padding: 0.2em 0;
}

/* ==========================================================================
   Author's custom styles
   ========================================================================== */

#nav {
     margin-left: -9px;
    }

.logo{
        display: block; margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto; margin-top:-300px; z-index:1;
    }


.center
{
    margin: 0 auto; 
}

#nav {
     margin-left: -9px;
}

ul{
        list-style-type:none; margin-left:50px; padding:0; margin-top: 0px; 
    }
    li{
        float:left;
    }
    li a:link,li a:visited{

        display:block;
        height: 83px;
        width:240px;
        z-index:-1;
        color:#ffffff;
        background-color:#212121;
        text-align:center;
        padding:0px;
        border: 0;
    }
    li a:hover,li a:active{
        background-color:#171616;
    }








/* ==========================================================================
   Helper classes
   ========================================================================== */

/*
 * Image replacement
 */

.ir {
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    /* IE 6/7 fallback */
    *text-indent: -9999px;
}

.ir:before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    height: 150%;
}

/*
 * Hide from both screenreaders and browsers: h5bp.com/u
 */

.hidden {
    display: none !important;
    visibility: hidden;
}

/*
 * Hide only visually, but have it available for screenreaders: h5bp.com/v
 */

.visuallyhidden {
    border: 0;
    clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
    height: 1px;
    margin: -1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 1px;
}

/*
 * Extends the .visuallyhidden class to allow the element to be focusable
 * when navigated to via the keyboard: h5bp.com/p
 */

.visuallyhidden.focusable:active,
.visuallyhidden.focusable:focus {
    clip: auto;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: visible;
    position: static;
    width: auto;
}

/*
 * Hide visually and from screenreaders, but maintain layout
 */

.invisible {
    visibility: hidden;
}

/*
 * Clearfix: contain floats
 *
 * For modern browsers
 * 1. The space content is one way to avoid an Opera bug when the
 *    `contenteditable` attribute is included anywhere else in the document.
 *    Otherwise it causes space to appear at the top and bottom of elements
 *    that receive the `clearfix` class.
 * 2. The use of `table` rather than `block` is only necessary if using
 *    `:before` to contain the top-margins of child elements.
 */

.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
    content: " "; /* 1 */
    display: table; /* 2 */
}

.clearfix:after {
    clear: both;
}

/*
 * For IE 6/7 only
 * Include this rule to trigger hasLayout and contain floats.
 */

.clearfix {
    *zoom: 1;
}

/* ==========================================================================
   EXAMPLE Media Queries for Responsive Design.
   These examples override the primary ('mobile first') styles.
   Modify as content requires.
   ========================================================================== */

@media only screen and (min-width: 35em) {
    /* Style adjustments for viewports that meet the condition */
}

@media print,
       (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 5/4),
       (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.25),
       (min-resolution: 120dpi) {
    /* Style adjustments for high resolution devices */
}

/* ==========================================================================
   Print styles.
   Inlined to avoid required HTTP connection: h5bp.com/r
   ========================================================================== */

@media print {
    * {
        background: transparent !important;
        color: #000 !important; /* Black prints faster: h5bp.com/s */
        box-shadow: none !important;
        text-shadow: none !important;
    }

    a,
    a:visited {
        text-decoration: underline;
    }

    a[href]:after {
        content: " (" attr(href) ")";
    }

    abbr[title]:after {
        content: " (" attr(title) ")";
    }

    /*
     * Don't show links for images, or javascript/internal links
     */

    .ir a:after,
    a[href^="javascript:"]:after,
    a[href^="#"]:after {
        content: "";
    }

    pre,
    blockquote {
        border: 1px solid #999;
        page-break-inside: avoid;
    }

    thead {
        display: table-header-group; /* h5bp.com/t */
    }

    tr,
    img {
        page-break-inside: avoid;
    }

    img {
        max-width: 100% !important;
    }

    @page {
        margin: 0.5cm;
    }

    p,
    h2,
    h3 {
        orphans: 3;
        widows: 3;
    }

    h2,
    h3 {
        page-break-after: avoid;
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
        <title></title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

        <!-- Place favicon.ico and apple-touch-icon.png in the root directory -->

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
        <script src="js/vendor/modernizr-2.6.2.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!--[if lt IE 7]>
            <p class="chromeframe">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> or <a href="http://www.google.com/chromeframe/?redirect=true">activate Google Chrome Frame</a> to improve your experience.</p>
        <![endif]-->

        <!-- Add your site or application content here -->
        <header>
                <div class="center" id="nav">
                        <img src="./img/head2.png" id="headb" />
                        <img src="./img/logo2.png" id="logo" class="logo" />
                </div>

        <nav>

    <div class="center" id="nav">
    <ul class="center">
<li><a href="index2.html"><img src="img/homeY2.png" class="navI" /></a></li>
<li><a href="forum.html"><img src="img/forum.png" class="navI" /></a></li>
<li><a href="about2.html"><img src="img/about2.png" class="navI" /></a></li>
<li><a href="media2.html"><img src="img/media2.png" class="navI" /></a></li>
<li><a href="port2.html"><img src="img/port2.png"  class="navI" /></a></li>
<li><a href="store2.html"><img src="img/store2.png" class="navI" /></a></li>
<li><a href="contact2.html"><img src="img/contact2.png" class="navI" /></a></li>
<li><a href="home2.html"><img src="img/more.png" class="navI" /></a></li>
</ul>
    </div>

</nav>

</header>



        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
        <script src="js/plugins.js"></script>
        <script src="js/main.js"></script>

        <!-- Google Analytics: change UA-XXXXX-X to be your site's ID. -->
        <script>
            var _gaq=[['_setAccount','UA-XXXXX-X'],['_trackPageview']];
            (function(d,t){var g=d.createElement(t),s=d.getElementsByTagName(t)[0];
            g.src='//www.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
            s.parentNode.insertBefore(g,s)}(document,'script'));
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you provide a link? Or could you perhaps paste your code in jsbin.com so we may see what is going on exactly?

Comment: its probably the path, see my updated answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Background Image not working with HTML5 Boilerplate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10452812/background-image-not-working-with-html5-boilerplate)

Answer (score 0):

you don't have parenthesis around your link

```
body {
font-size: 1em;
line-height: 1.4;
background-image: url ("img/bg2.png");
background-repeat: no-repeat;

}
```

Comment: They're not needed for `url()`

Answer (score 0):

For some reason you seem to have to do them separately but this fiddle works:

CSS:

```
body {
    background-image: url('http://i.dailymail.co.uk/i/pix/2012/11/15/article-0-1609D0FF000005DC-373_964x641.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/VWbGq/

Comment: I tried you exact code and still nothing, i think the problem lies somewhere else

Comment: shorthand goes like this background: prop1 prop2; if thats what you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

Pls see this question too:

[Background Image not working with HTML5 Boilerplate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10452812/background-image-not-working-with-html5-boilerplate?rq=1)

In CSS The paths are relative **to the css file it self**.

Where is the css? In css folder. Where is the img folder containing the images? Probably not in the css folder.

This means in your css file you need to use paths like this:

```
url("../img/file.jpg);
```

This means "Go one level up, look for a folder called img, go inside, give me file.jpg."

The way you have your path would imply the img folder is in your css folder, which probably is not the case.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be specificity, and the path had been double checked. But it may be another element hiding it. I have posted the full css.

Comment: pls post the html as well.

Comment: its probably the path, as mentioned the path needs to be relative to your css file, not html file

Comment: I actually didn't know that thanks. I've made the appropriate changes but still no luck, i'm now sure the path is right. I'm close to giving up on boilerplate

Comment: So you changed background-image: url (img/bg2.png);
to background-image: url (../img/bg2.png); ? Can you assign other values, like a border?

Comment: the problem can not be boilerplate. thats super basic setup. Something simple is mixed up here.

Comment: Yes i agree it proably is something simple i just can;t figure it out, i changed it to background-image:url(../img/bg2.png)

Comment: Just tried borders, it makes a border around a small segment of the page at the very top

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell in Firebug the normalize.css is overriding the background now. (line 72)